# Adding a custom post type taxonomy template in plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

I've created a custom post type named "accommodation" and taxonomy for it named "categories" using the file "taxonomy-accommodation-categories.php" - this is working fine in my WordPress theme.

But I want to add this in a separate plugin instead, does anyone know how I can do this?

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Take a look at my own question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204710/is-there-a-way-to-optimize-function-that-is-used-for-returning-data-in-an-ajax-c   I think you will found what you're looking for there in my code.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'taxonomy_template');
function taxonomy_template( $template ){

if( is_tax('accommodation-categories')){
    $template = BASE_DIR .'/templates/taxonomy-accommodation-categories.php';
}  

return $template;

}
```

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to your code

Answer (score 0):

You can create Page template in your plugin and add following filter which will called template from your plugin

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpa3396_page_template' );
function wpa3396_page_template( $page_template )
{
    if ( is_page( 'my-custom-texonomy-slug' ) ) {
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/template-neme.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that was close but didn't work. I found the is_tax function and this works is_tax('accommodation-categories')

Comment: `page_template` is only for the `page` post type, `taxonomy_template` is the filter for taxonomies.